# How to find a prime q such that it divides prime p-1?

Tags: divide, factorization

I would like to find a prime q such that it divides a prime p-1

E.g. p=23 (prime)
q|p-1 = 11|22

Are there any formula for doing so if prime p is not always a safe prime?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.  It may belong on the math stackexchange.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming. [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) is for Math.